# magento phtml file infinite scroll via ajax data?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a text box and a div associated with this, I need to show data via ajax query, because via autoload js data is showing very slow in div that give suggestion box effect?

I just want that , if I type 3 letter in textbox an div appear as dropdown for textbox and fetch data based similar like data in textbox (via like statement in query's where clause) and show 5 records in div, when I will scroll it show more 5 records then if I scroll again, 5 new.

How can achieve this.
thanks.